# Using HTML content in VBScript in the same file

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I have this code which contains mixed VBScript and HTML:

```
IF (x.name="name") THEN
    n=x.value
    response.write("<tr>")
    response.write("<th>Name:</th>")
    response.write("<td><input name=""n2"" value=" & n & "></input></td>")
    response.write("</tr>")
'...
```

and I want the to use the content of the input tag inside VBScript in the same file.

I tried this:

```
   <% dim name
   name=request.form("n2")%>
```

but when I tried printing it using `Response.Write` it will be empty which means it didn't take the current content in the form field.

How to get it in VBScript while being in the same page?

Comment: This is not mixed VBScript and HTML, it's pure classic ASP written with VBScript that sends HTML to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access data using Request.Form you need to POST the contents of the input field back to the same page.

```
response.write("<form method=""post"" action=""yourpage.asp"">")
response.write("<table>")
response.write("<tr>")
response.write("<th>Name:</th>")
response.write("<td><input type=""text"" name=""n2"" value=""" & n & """/></td>")
response.write("</table>")
response.write("<input type=""submit"" value=""Submit"" name=""submit""/>")
response.write("</form>")
```

Then you can use Request.Form to get the request contents of the form post. The Form collection retrieves the values of form elements posted to the HTTP request body, with a form using the POST method.

```
Dim name
name = Request.Form("n2")
response.write("name")
```

Comment: i tried this but didn't work at all it will get me an empty string.. another solution please ?

Comment: thank you so much worked perfectly, i didn't put the submit button after i did everything worked perfect. thanks!